# Getting two user access_token from Linkedin

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am working on login with linkedin process.

I am surprised linkedin is returning two `access_tokens` and `access_token_secretes`.

The first `access_token` is returned in `session` as

```
Array
(
    [OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN] => Array
        (
            [https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken] => Array
                (
                    [value] => some_access_token_string
                    [secret] => access_token_secrete
                    [authorized] => 
                )

        )

)
```

and also in

`$client = new oauth_client_class;`

the class object `$client`, after authentication linkedin is returning

```
  ["access_token"]=> "some_other_access_token"
  ["access_token_secret"]=> "some_other_access_token_secrete"
  ["access_token_expiry"]=> "2017-09-13 06:36:10"
  ["access_token_type"]=> ""
  ["default_access_token_type"]=> ""
  ["access_token_parameter"]=> ""
  ["access_token_response"]=> NULL
  ["store_access_token_response"]=> false
  ["access_token_authentication"]=> ""
  ["refresh_token"]=> ""
```

now i'm confused which `access_token` and `access_token_secrete` value should I store in db for future use ?

Comment: Look at documentation - it should clarify everything :) https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/best-practices#keysecret

Comment: i'm still confused :(

Comment: It depends what do you actually want to request. Which parameter is required for methods which you will be calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`["access_token"]=> "some_other_access_token"` this will meet your need.

but you can read complete documentation here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/best-practices#keysecret